# How to compare elements in an object and return the higher value? *Javascript*

Tags: javascript, loops, object, for-in-loop

I am trying to compare two elements inside an object in Javascript. The letter that has the highest value, should be returned along with the number it carries.

This is the object and we should return a and 39.

```
obj({a:39,b:21,c:12,d:4}) // should return a : 39
```

Here is my code so far.

```
let obj = object => {

  for(let i in object) { // i  represents the "key" of the objects, a,b,c,d
    if(object[i] > object[i + 1]) { // object[i] represents the "value" held 39,21,12,4
      console.log(i + ":" + object[i]);
    } else {
      console.log(i + ":" + object[i]);
    }
  }
}

obj({a:39,b:21,c:12,d:4})
```

I thought object[i + 1] in the if statement would compare the next indexed element to the current one but it doesn't, how would you accomplish this?

**EDIT** *if there are two elements with the same value then return both of the elements*

This is probably the easiest way to accomplish this for people new to coding like me. This code returns the highest number held in the object.

```
let getMax = (obj) => {
  let highestValue = 0;
  for(var i in obj) {
    if(highestValue < obj[i]) {
      highestValue = obj[i];
    } else if (highestValue == obj[i]) {
      highestValue = highestValue + " " + obj[i];
    }
  }
  alert(highestValue);
}
getMax({John:300000,Kary:360000,David:2700000,Michelle:2700000})
```

Comment: You probably want to use `Object.keys()` and iterate through those as an array. You can then look ahead with `i+1` being the index of the next key. Obviously make sure you don't look past the end of the keys array then.

Comment: what happens with more than one max property?

Comment: Thanks veddermatic. I was wondering how to look ahead like with an array. you cleared it up : )

Comment: good question Nina. if more than one max property then return both. I will try to edit the question.

Comment: Why did you think `object[i + 1]` would compare the next element? When `i` is `"a"` then `i + 1` is `"a1"`, not `"b"`. It's an object, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each iteration check if the current or previous key value is the largest, and store. Store the largest in the `largest` variable. In the end return the `largest` variable, and it's value (`object[largest]`):

```js
let obj = object => {
  let largest;
  for(const i in object) { // i  represents the "key" of the objects, a,b,c,d
    if(!largest || object[i] > object[largest]) {
      largest = i;
    }
  }
  
  return { [largest]: object[largest] };
}

console.log(obj({a:39,b:21,c:12,d:4}));
```

**Suggested solution:**

Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get key|value pairs. Iterate with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), choose the pair with the highest value (index 1). [Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the reduce's result (an array with `[key, value]`) into `key` and value consts, and use them to build the return object.

```js
const obj = (object) => {
  const [key, value] = Object.entries(object)
    .reduce((r, e) => e[1] > r[1] ? e : r);
  return { [key]: value };
};
  
console.log(obj({a:39,b:21,c:12,d:4}));
```

Comment: why do you do const[key, value] what does that mean?

Comment: The result of the reduce is an array in the form of `[key, value]`. I want to break (destructure) to `key` and `value` const that I need for the creation of the object that the function will return.

Comment: I understand your approach now and I like it, thank you for breaking it down for me.

Answer (score 1):

`for(let i in object)`

returns object keys

so i+1 = a : a1, b:b1, c:c1

This will be the correct code:

```
let obj = object => {
let returnValue;
for(let i in object) { // i  represents the "key" of the objects, a,b,c,d
  if(typeof(returnValue)==="undefined"){
    returnValue = object[i];
  } else if (object[i] > returnValue) {
    returnValue=object[i];
  }
}
return returnValue;
}
obj({a:39,b:21,c:12,d:4})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could collect the keys and the render the object with the max values.

```js
function getMax(object) {
    return Object.assign(
        ...Object
            .keys(object).reduce((r, k) => {
                if (!r || object[r[0]] < object[k]) {
                    return [k];
                }
                if (object[r[0]] === object[k]) {
                    r.push(k);
                }
                return r;
            }, undefined)
            .map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] }))
    );
}

console.log(getMax({ a: 39, b: 21, c: 12, d: 4, foo: 39 }));
```

Comment: Kind of ahead of my skill level, but i'm going to study your code and learn it, it will make me better. Thanks for taking the time to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

When you do `let i in object`, you're iterating through every *key* in the object. So in this case, `i` would be a, b, c, and d, respectively after each iteration.

That's why `object[i+1]` doesn't work. Because on the first iteration when `i` is "a", the interpretter reads it as `object['a' + 1]` which results to `object['a1']`.

There's a few ways you can approach this.

One method would be to use the `Object` class's `keys` function, which returns an array of keys and then you can call `map` on that result to loop through each key and you'll also have a index to each one. I.e:

```
let obj = object => {
  var keys = Object.keys(object);
  keys.map(function(key, index) {
    console.log("Current value: " + object[key]);
    console.log("Current index: " + index);
    console.log("Current key: " + key);
    console.log("Next value: " + object[keys[index + 1]]); // you should probably check if you're at the last index before you do this
    console.log("-------------");
  });
};
obj( {a:39,b:21,c:12,d:4} );
```

Another route you can go is using a for loop and creating an iterator variable, like so:

```
let obj = object => {
  var keys = Object.keys(object);

  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    console.log('Current Value: ' + object[keys[i]]);
    console.log('Next Value: ' + object[keys[i + 1]]); // also probably do a check here to see if you're already at the last index
  }
};
obj( {a:39,b:21,c:12,d:4} );
```

In the case above, `i` would always be a number. Then we loop through the number of keys there are in the object, and then use `i` to get the key we want. Then put that key into the object and we'll get the values you want to compare by.

Answer (score 0):

To get all index/value (if exists multiple max values),

1. use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get key/value pairs,
2. then when using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to loop the pairs, set the initial value of reduce = `{max:0, data:[]}`

Comment: **max** saves the max value, **data** saves the pairs with max value.
And assuming the values is > 0, so set the initial value of max = 0 (you can change the initial value as you need).

3. In the loop, compare the value,

if `cur > max`, push it into pre.data and update pre.max.

if `cur===max`, push it to pre.data,

if `cur<max`, do nothing.

```js
const obj = {a:39,b:21,c:12,d:4,e:39}
result = Object.entries(obj).reduce(function(pre, cur){
  if(pre.max < cur[1]){
    pre.data = []
    pre.max = cur[1]
    pre.data.push({[cur[0]]:cur[1]})
  }
  else if(pre.max === cur[1]){
    pre.data.push({[cur[0]]:cur[1]})
  }
  return pre
},{max:0, data:[]})
console.log(result.data)
```